# How to display correctly image with icc color profile embed?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Under delphi tokyo, If i try to show this image:

https://chromachecker.com/include/img/web_browser/redtruck_GBR.jpg

[image]

Inside a Timage then instead of a blue sky it's show a **GREEN** sky like below :

[image]

How in delphi we can show correctly picture with embed color profile ?

Comment: Well, not with [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net) (which is used in Delphi). Nor with [libjpeg-turbo](https://www.libjpeg-turbo.org) library. The latter [has had](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/commit/44b2399a940869920b659f3cdbfc32ffecb37364) ICC profile reading and writing support for a while. But the developers removed that later. Yet, it was able to read and write ICC just as raw data.

Comment: Use a library that can handle ICC, or implement it. Either way, this is off topic.

Comment: @LURD did I ask for a library? do you know that android > oreo and ios support icc natively ? can you clarify exactly what is "off topic" ??

Comment: There is no mention of mobile in your question. And since there is no built in icc color support in Delphi, there are two options left: 1) Use an external library, which is off topic. 2) Implement icc support by code, which is off topic as too broad.

Comment: @LURD: are you sure we can not handle icc support via opengl / texture ? android and ios and macos have native support for icc, why not windows? and most important, for you if the question have no easy solution (or solution you know) then it's immediately off topic ! great ;) NB: i m ironic of course !

Comment: I have no problem viewing the image in windows. Also , I did not say that the question had no easy solution. Only that the easy solution implies a link to a library (in Delphi) that can handle it. And from what was discussed yesterday, we are supposed to refrain from giving such links here.

Comment: so giving this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372179(v=vs.85).aspx and a little speech to say how to use it is forbidden ???(?)

Comment: No, but that won't resolve what you ask. You cannot display images by that API. You can manipulate ICC profiles with it, but not display the output. I guess [WIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902(v=vs.85).aspx) could use some more advanced decoder. Yet, it's just the Windows platform.

Comment: @victoria: i justed want to show to LURD that this question is not off topic, and solution that involve only the os api are available ...

Comment: Well, even WIC doesn't handle this correctly. In Windows Explorer and that default imaging application it shows correctly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete answer and example is way too broad. But here's a rough outline what you need to do. See it as a starting point for further research.

1. Get the color profile of your image. Either the EXIF data refers to a well known profile, or it is embedded in the image metadata.
2. Get the color profile of the screen `GetICMProfile`
3. Load the color profiles of the screen and your image: `OpenColorProfile`
4. Create the color transform: `CreateMultiProfileTransform`
5. Translate the colors: `TranslateBitmapBits`
6. Clean up: `CloseColorProfile`, `DeleteColorTransform`